# apacite: full name in bibliography but only surname in in-text citation

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, apacite

I am using the package,

```
\usepackage[natbibapa,natbib]{apacite}

\begin{document}

As indicated by \citealt{burton2015targeted}, the story can be effective. 

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\end{document}
```

and this is what I have in my bibliography.bib file,

```
@article{burton2015targeted,
  title={Targeted construction storyboards in semantic fieldwork},
  author={Burton, Strang and Matthewson, Lisa},
  journal={Methodologies in semantic fieldwork},
  pages={135--156},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Oxford University Press Oxford}
}
```

and what I am trying to accomplish is to have full name (surname, completeFirstName) in the bibliography but just surname in the in-text citation.

so the desired output would be,

```
in-text: As indicated by Burton and Matthewson (2015), the story can be effective.

bibliography

Burton, Strang and Matthewson, Lisa. Targeted construction storyboards in semantic fieldwork. Methodologies in semantic fieldwork. 2015. 135–156.
```

I have tried the double curls brackets {{}} for the author's name but the problem is that the full name also appears in in-text citation. I also tried, citet*,citet,...etc but never seem to get what I want.

Comment: But the APA manual does not want first names to be printed in full in the reference list. If you want this, then you should not use `apacite`.

Comment: thank you for your reply, do you have any suggestions on what package i should use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you should proceed if you want to keep using the `apacite` bibliography style and the `apacite` citation management package.

- Find the file `apacite.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the file, say, `apacite-full.bst`. (Do not edit an original file from the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `apacite-full.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In the file `apacite-full.bst`, locate the following line:

  ```
  FUNCTION {initials.with.space.name.format} { "{f.}" }
  ```

  (In my copy of the file, it's line 2067.)
- Change it to

  ```
  FUNCTION {initials.with.space.name.format} { "{ff}" }
  ```
- Save the file `apacite-full.bst`, either in the directory where your main tex files are located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably. If you don't understand the preceding sentence, I suggest you choose the first option.
- In the main tex file, change the instruction

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{apacite}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{apacite-full}
  ```

  and perform a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to fully propagate the changes.

A separate comment: It's *wrong* to use the `@article` entry type for entry at hand. Instead, you should be using the `@incollection` entry type, change the `journal` field to `booktitle`, backfill the missing `editor` field, and split the `publisher` field into separate `publisher` and `address` fields.

---

An MWE (minimum working example) and its output -- observe the use of untruncated first names:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bibliography.bib}
@incollection{burton2015targeted,
  title={Targeted construction storyboards in semantic fieldwork},
  author={Burton, Strang and Matthewson, Lisa},
  booktitle={Methodologies in Semantic Fieldwork},
  editor={M. Ryan Bochnak and Lisa Matthewson},
  chapter={6},
  pages={135--156},
  year={2015},
  address={Oxford},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite-full}

\begin{document}
As indicated by \citealt{burton2015targeted}, the story can be effective. 
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [Denis'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/49497/denis)answer above I could solve the in-text citation, but for the bibliography to appear as for example(surname, complete firstname and surname, complete first name) I had to make changes directly in the .bst file of the plainnat as suggested by Denis in the comments.
To let you know on what I did, I made changes to the following function

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
```

instead of "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}", I added "{vv~}{ll}{, ff}{, jj}" to get my desired output. and then added the .bst file with a new name in my \bibliographystyle{mystyle} for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using `natbib` although most people now turn to `biblatex`. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{round}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{burton2015targeted,
  title={Targeted construction storyboards in semantic fieldwork},
  author={Burton, Strang and Matthewson, Lisa},
  journal={Methodologies in semantic fieldwork},
  pages={135--156},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Oxford University Press Oxford}
}
\end{filecontents}
\citealt{burton2015targeted}

\citet{burton2015targeted}

\citep{burton2015targeted}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

to obtain

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, is there anyway I can get Burton, Strang and Matthewson, Lisa. in the reference section

Comment: This is an unsual request: it will require tweaking the bst style. No time to do that now.

Comment: ok, I see. thanks anyways

Comment: The opening sentence of your answer is borderline misleading, as what you're actually suggesting is not so much the use of the `natbib` citation management package but, rather, the use of a completly different bib style that has practically nothing in common with the `apacite` bib style.

Comment: @Mico The OP wants first names to be printed. The rules of APA does not allow this. Hence `apacite` does not allow this. What should I do then? `natbib`offers a simple solution. And I said you `could` not you `must`.

Comment: @Denis - With their own words, the OP has made clear that they're quite aware they'd be going against APA formatting guidelines. By renaming the `apacite` bib style to `apacite-full`, say, and applying the needed change to `apacite-full` (feel free to choose a different name), one  can make quite clear that the bib style no longer satisfies all formatting requirements laid down in the 6th edition of APA.